# Building an example module

Tags: opendaylight, maven-archetype

The ODL guide provides a command to generate the structure of a module depending on the desired version. But the version that works with the command indicated is very old.

Which version is required by the Argon version in the following command? Or is there any other method to obtain the structure of the applications of this version of ODL?

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
    -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=<VERSION>
```